# How to query sites inside a site collection using Microsoft Graph API C# SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have details for a Site Collection, such as name, ID, webURL.  Now I want to query the sites inside this site collection.  How do I actually do that using the C# SDK?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use the code from a similar question i posted here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328298/microsoft-graph-v5-query-site-collection-subsite-by-name

Answer (score 0):

With `siteId`, you can list subsites

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var result = await graphClient.Sites["{siteId}"].Sites.GetAsync();
```