# Microsoft Graph v5 Query Site Collection Subsite by name

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

When a Sharepoint site has a collection of subsites, **how to provide a QueryParameter to filter the site collection by Name**.

The records returned are ALL children sites from the 'parent' site Collection of Sites, but only the first 40 records (there are 800+).

```
public async Task<Site?> GetSiteSubSiteByNameAsync(string parentSiteId, string subSiteName)
{
    Site? subsite = null;
    var subSiteNameEndocded = System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(subSiteName);
    try
    {
        var request = _graphServiceClient
            .Sites[parentSiteId]
            .Sites
            .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "sites" };
                    //Filter does not get applied!???!
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"Name eq '{subSiteName}'";
                }
            );
        var subsiteCollection = await request;
        if (subsiteCollection != null && subsiteCollection.Value != null && subsiteCollection.Value.Count > 0)
        {
            subsite = subsiteCollection.Value[0];
            if (subsite == null || subsite == default)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"No Subsite({subSiteName})");
            }
            return subsite;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
    }
    return subsite;
}
```

Not a duplicate of ["how-to-query-sites-inside-a-site-collection-using-microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp-sd"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75670139/how-to-query-sites-inside-a-site-collection-using-microsoft-graph-api-c-sharp-sd)

Answer (score 1):

Filter by `name` or `displayName` doesn't work. You can use `$search` query parameter, but from my testing, it searches for sites that match the `displayName`.

```
var result = await graphClient.Sites[parentSiteId].Sites.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = $"{subSiteDisplayName}";
});
```

Alternatively, use double quotes

```
requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = $"\"subSiteDisplayName}\""
```

Comment: Try to remove `'`. This search parameter for sites is always tricky `requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Search = $"{subSiteDisplayName}";`

Comment: @OzBob Updated.